# Basic algebra proof review for the commutativity of a product

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am able to prove that the product of $x_{1}, ..., x_{n}$ is the same no matter how you order it in a commutative monoid $G$ if this theorem, along with its proof, is correct: http://mathbin.net/74656

I hope you don't mind that I wrote it in mathbin, it's just that I prefer using that. What I am asking for is basically a review of the proof because I'm not too sure it is formal and correct.

Comment: It looks more or less similar to [this proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71473/is-prod-i-1ra-i-b-i-prod-i-1ra-i-prod-i-1rb-i/71479#comment169143_71479), though you are doing induction on the image of $n$, whereas the proof I link to uses induction on the number of factors.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: That seems to be the same proof given in the book that I'm following (Lang's Algebra). I wanted to come up with my own proof (partly because I didn't feel like trying to completely understand his proof :p)

Comment: Yes, it is essentially the proof in Lang. Upon looking at your argument, though, I don't think it's right. I don't think your induction is correct: your induction hypothesis is that if $n$ is mapped to $k$, then the product over the permutation $\psi$ is the same as over the permutation $\psi'$. But in the inductive step, you are trying to perform a "shuffle" which is *not* your induction hypothesis, so I don't see how you justify the inductive step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me expand on my comment.

It seems that you are trying to prove a "one step" general commutativity, by showing that if you have a permutation $\psi\colon \{1,\ldots,n\}\to\{1,\ldots,n\}$ that "moves $n$", then you can replace it with a permutation $\psi'$ that has the same values as $\psi$ everywhere except at $n$ and at $\psi^{-1}(n)$; namely, if $\psi^{-1}(n)=k$, then you define
$$\phi(i) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\psi(i) &\text{if }i\neq k, i\neq n;\\
\psi(n) &\text{if }i=k;\\
n &\text{if }i=n.
\end{array}\right.$$
and then want to show that for any elements $a_1,\ldots,a_n\in M$,
$$\prod_{i=1}^n a_{\psi(i)} = \prod_{i=1}^{n}a_{\phi(n)}.$$

You try to argue by induction on $\delta=n-k$. When $k=1$, you have that $\psi(n-1)=n$, so
$$\begin{align*}
a_{\psi(1)}\cdots a_{\psi(n-1)}a_{\psi(n)} &= \bigl(a_{\phi(1)}\cdots a_{\phi(n-2)}\bigr)a_na_{\phi(n-1)}\\
&= \bigl(a_{\phi(1)}\cdots a_{\phi(n-2)}\bigr)a_{\phi(n-1)}a_n\\
&= a_{\phi(1)}\cdots a_{\phi(n-2)}a_{\phi(n-1})a_{\phi(n)},
\end{align*}$$
so you are fine.

Your induction hypothesis then is that if $\phi(k)=n$, then
$$\bigl(a_{\psi(1)}\cdots a_{\psi(k-1)}\bigr)a_n\bigl(a_{\psi(k+1)}\cdots a_{\psi(n)}\bigr) = \bigl( a_{\psi(1)}\cdots a_{\psi(k-1)}\bigr)\bigl(a_{\psi(k+1)}\cdots a_{\psi(n)}\bigr)a_n.$$
You then consider the situation in which $\phi(k-1)=n$. You have:
$$\bigl( a_{\psi(1)}\cdots a_{\psi(k-2)}\bigr) a_n \bigl( a_{\psi(k)}\cdots a_{\psi(n)}\bigr).$$
I cannot see how you are applying your induction hypothesis to go from here to
$$\bigl( a_{\psi(1)}\cdots a_{\psi(k-2)}\bigr)a_{\psi(n)}\bigl(a_{\psi(k)}\cdots a_{\psi(n-1)}\bigr) a_{n}.$$
Rather, you seem to be applying associativity and a two-step binary commutativity. If this is the case, then why muddie the waters with an unnecessary proof "by induction"? You aren't *really* doing induction, you are using associativity and binary commutativity.

Simply let $k$ be the element such that $\psi(k) = n$. Then
$$\begin{align*}
a_{\psi(1)}\cdots a_{\psi(n)} &= \Bigl(a_{\psi(1)}\cdots a_{\psi(k-1)}\Bigr)a_{\psi(k)}\Bigl(\bigl(a_{\psi(k+1)}\cdots a_{\psi(n-1)}\bigr)a_{\psi(n)}\Bigr)\\
&=  \Bigl(a_{\phi(1)}\cdots a_{\phi(k-1)}\Bigr)a_{n}\Bigl(\bigl(a_{\phi(k+1)}\cdots a_{\phi(n-1)}\bigr)a_{\phi(k)}\Bigr)\\
&=  \Bigl(a_{\phi(1)}\cdots a_{\phi(k-1)}\Bigr)a_{n}\Bigl(a_{\phi(k)}\bigl(a_{\phi(k+1)}\cdots a_{\phi(n-1)}\bigr)\Bigr)\\
&= \Bigl(a_{\phi(1)}\cdots a_{\phi(k-1)}\Bigr)\Bigl(a_{\phi(k)}\bigl(a_{\phi(k+1)}\cdots a_{\phi(n-1)}\bigr)\Bigr)a_n\\
&= a_{\phi(1)}\cdots a_{\phi(k-1)}a_{\phi(k)}a_{\phi(k+1)}\cdots a_{\phi(n-1)}a_{\phi(n)}\\
&= a_{\phi(1)}\cdots a_{\phi(n)},
\end{align*}$$
as desired; first equality holds by general associativity; second by the definition of $\phi$; third by commuting the elements $a_{\phi(k)}$ and $(a_{\phi(k+1)}\cdots a_{\phi(n-1)})$; fourth by commuting $a_n$ with the factor $(a_{\phi(k)}(a_{\phi(k+1)}\cdots a_{\phi(n-1)}))$, and fifth by general associativity.

Of course, then you'll want to do an induction on $n$ to finish the proof, having applied the first step to reduce the problem from a permutation of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ to a permutation of $\{1,\ldots,n-1\}$ extended identically to $\{1,\ldots,n\}$...

Comment: Now that's what I'd call "expanding on a comment"! :-)

Comment: Yes, Arturo. I did later notice that I wasn't really using the inductive hypothesis. I'm going to rewrite the proof. Thanks for taking the time to look through it!